# keras load_model stuck in loading state

Tags: tensorflow, keras, save

I am training a model using keras, and it trains great. I get clear results, and i can even save it with model.save('saved_model'). However when I try to load the 20mb model again with load_model('saved_model'), it stalls, eating up one of my processors at 100%, but even after a half hour of waiting it does not load. Here is my code:

```
    callbacks = ModelCheckpoint('_checkpoint',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='min')
    model = _keras_compiled_model(x_dim,y_dim,len(labels))
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                        callbacks=[callbacks])

    # load the model with the best validation loss, delete checkpount data
    model.load_weights('_checkpoint')
    model.save('saved_model')
```

What could I be doing wrong here? keras, Tensorflow 2.0, 1080ti, Windows 10

Comment: I seem to have success with pickling, ill just go ahead and use the pickling binarizer instead of the tensorflow internal.